# Creating an accordion-like animation for a new element inserted with a JQuery Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

How can I animate a new element that's inserted via a JQuery template? Rather than just having it appear suddenly, I'd rather have it come in almost like an accordion where it starts at 0 height and expands to it's full height.

How would I go about doing this?

Example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zvn1yju2/

Code Snippet:

```js
$('.ui.button').on('click', function() {
  $('#testTemplate').tmpl().appendTo("#testDiv");
});
```

```css
        .column:not(.row):not(.grid):after {
          background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .01);
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2) inset;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2) inset;
          content: "";
          display: block;
          min-height: 50px;
        }
        
        .greyDiv {
          height:150px;
          width: 150px;
          background: grey;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="ui grid container">
    <div class="four wide column">
      <button class="ui button">
        Insert Template
      </button>
      <div id="testDiv"></div>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>

<script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div class="ui input greyDiv">
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `hide()` on template and use `slideDown()` or any other animation effect

```
$('.ui.button').on('click', function() {
   var $tmp =$('#testTemplate').tmpl().hide();
   $("#testDiv").append($tmp);
   $tmp.slideDown();
});
```

You can also do this with css animations

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zvn1yju2/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: That works great! Out of curiosity, why does this work with `$("#testDiv").append($tmp);` and not `$($tmp).tmpl().appendTo("#testDiv");` ? If you don't mind also adding this to your answer: How can you make this work with css animations?